# How did vim do internally so that pressing one `y` doesn't wait for the second `y` for the `yy` key map?

Tags: vim, neovim

Normally if i define key maps that require 2 keys pressing the first one will wait for the second key, but keys like `y` are executed immediately while `yy` still works. Can this be achieved with vimscript?

Comment: What do you mean, `y` is evaluated immediately? In normal mode, `y` will switch to operator pending mode, which will wait for a text object or a motion. You're right in that the wait from operator pending mode is not the same as the wait from the multi-key mapping, but... can you describe better what you're trying to do (and what do you mean by `y` doesn't wait")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is how it works.

When you press y, it **IS** waiting for an input, it's waiting for you to give the motion.

If you look at `h: y` and `h: yy` you will see they say that `y` yanks {motion} text into register. The `y` command does not actually yank the text until you press at least the second key, to indicate the direction. The typical use-case for `y` would be something more like `y4l` to yank the 4 characters to the right.

When you provide another `y` keypress instead of a motion, this is a special case in which it just yanks from the start of the line to the newline.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! and also i found this article made it really clear http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/16.html

Comment: It's a pleasure, and that's an excellent resource and a great place to learn. I'd really recommend reading up as much about these kind of things even if you don't implement them, just because you never know when it does come up.

Comment: yes it's a great great resource, learning and tweaking vim is addictive 